# Auto complete/Suggest in Wordpress Form

Tags: autocomplete, wordpress

I'm placing a search form of 6 fields on my home page which includes a text box field named course. I want to show course suggestions while user typing. One more is, I want to show/hide some fields according to the option of first field dropdown. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need it to suggests post titles that have matching text?

Comment: Have you done research on this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AnjuRaghunath - It is not for post titles. I want to show some course suggestions like Java,SAP,etc.

Comment: @msbodetti - Yes, I did research on it but I'm not that good in Wordpress customization. So came here for some help.

Comment: @Kishor Kumar you need to add those manually or these course suggestions are added as posts through admin panel?

Comment: @AnjuRaghunath - I will add these courses using some custom post type. Could you please tell me then how can I integrate this post category posts to a single text box field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Auto Suggest which is included with WordPress : [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

With this you can write a form that does a Ajax lookup to the the Ajax URL handler. Which you can add_action onto. [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

So you can ajax lookup and then on the action side you can just perform a get_posts to match titles, or a raw sql Query. And return what is needed. edit your functions.php.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function se_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
}

add_action('wp_head', 'se_wp_head');
function se_wp_head() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#se_search_element_id').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup');
    });
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');

function se_lookup() {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = like_escape($_REQUEST['q']);

    $query = 'SELECT ID,post_title FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . '
        WHERE post_title LIKE \'' . $search . '%\'
        AND post_type = \'post_type_name\'
        AND post_status = \'publish\'
        ORDER BY post_title ASC';
    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query) as $row) {
        $post_title = $row->post_title;
        $id = $row->ID;

        $meta = get_post_meta($id, 'YOUR_METANAME', TRUE);

        echo $post_title . ' (' . $meta . ')' . "\n";
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Anju Raghunath. I'm applying it. I'll be back after trying it.

Comment: You took this from a different post and wrote it as your own answer :S

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax for both. You may have to write some mysql query to retrieve the required fields(post titles or whatever it is) from the table.

Comment: its not the answer to the question.